# php , I want to build array from 12 values each value has max number of 2048

Tags: php, arrays, build, numbers, integer

I want to build array from 12 values each value has max number of 2048

```
Array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

Max Array [2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048,2048]
```

Now I want to tell php to increase the Array with number 1, 2, 3, 3000
and it should be like

```
Array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]
Array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13]
Array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,14]

Array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3011]
```

when I try to add number > 2048 the Array show error , is it possible to do and how ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Why? `$arr = []; foreach (range(0, 11) as $i) { $arr[$i] = range(0, 2048); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $num_array=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
>
> ```
> for($i=12;$i<=2048;$i++)
> {
>     array_push($num_array,$i);
> }
> ```